# Insert Variable in dataframe name

Tags: dataframe

> I have a dataframe called df_yearly, which consists of approximately 75,000 rows and 359 columns, with a multi index (Ticker, Date). I want to create a subset of the data frame, and name the new dataframe using the ticker variable as part of the data frame name.
>
> > `ticker = "META"`
> > `df_ticker = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')`
>
> this works to create a new dataframe, df_ticker. What Id like to do is create a dataframe, df_(insert ticker value here)
>
> I tried:
>
> > `f"df_{ticker}" = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')`
>
> and got the following error:
> f"df_{ticker}" = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')
> Cell In[173], line 1
> f"df_{ticker}" = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')
>
> > ```
> > ^
> > ```
>
> SyntaxError: cannot assign to f-string expression
>
> > `
>
> I tried:
>
> > `"df_" + ticker = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')`
>
> and got the following error:
>
> > `"df_"+ticker = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker') Cell In[175], line 1 "df_"+ticker = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker') ^ SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator`
>
> I tried:
>
> > `"".join(["df_", ticker]) = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')`
>
> and got the following error:
>
> > `"".join(["df_", ticker]) = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')
> > Cell In[176], line 1
> > "".join(["df_", ticker]) = df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')
> > ^
> > SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
>
> I would like to substitute "ticker" in df_ticker for the variable ticker, so that
> I create the data frame df_META, which is df_yearly.query('Ticker in @ticker')
>
> I want to create a different dataframe for a bunch of tickers, with separate dataframe names so i can save them individually to excel worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate answer is that you really shouldn't do this. While it's possible to create new variables automatically and assign things to them with things like `exec` and `eval`, it's just not the right answer, and you should look for a different solution to what you're trying to do.

You don't want a variable that you didn't name and/or don't know how to access, and you especially don't want to be using `exec` or `eval` in something that anyone not you is going to use. The answer here, even though it might not seem like it, is to use a dictionary, adjusting names of keys as needed.

```py
things = {
    'df' : df,
    'ticker' : df[some_logic].something().blah()
}

...

for key in things:
    print(f'{things[key].__class__.__name__} @{key.title()}')
```

Edit:
and add keys to the dict like you tried with your variables:

```py
things[ f'df_{col_name}' ] = df[col_name].query('something')
```